# How to forward traffic with a router from subnet

Tags: router, nat, subnet, gateway

To setup wlan in an office environment I want the Wifi-Users to be in a different subnet than the office clients. I need help with the router-settings.

---

**The Setup I want**

`Office: 192.168.178.0/24` | 
`Wlan: 10.0.0.0/24`

*The router should connect these two networks (see graphic):*
*One could say, the router would "host" the 10.0.0.0 network and forward traffic incoming from the Access-Points through Lan-port 1 to 192.168.178.1*
[image]

**The yellow box contains settings I am unsure what to choose. Can one help me out with these settings?**

---

**Router IP**

*Should the router-ip be in 192.168.178.0 (office) or in 10.0.0.0 (wlan)? I want the wlan-clients to get dyn IP's from DHCP of the linksys, but DHCP-Settings rely on the Router-IP, therefor It seems it has to be a 10.0.0.1 Can one clearify this?*
[image]

---

**Additional Questions:**

I did not find an "enable NAT" setting in the NAT-Menue(s). Does one know how to activate NAT (if required for the setup?)

Anything else I need to know to achieve this setup?

I am incredibly thankful for any help!

Comment: Well, lets start off with more info. Can you tell us what  are the model numbers for the router and access points?

Comment: Router is a Linksys WRTG54, APs are TP-Link TL-WA801ND.

Comment: On the Linksys "Gateway Mode" == "NAT Enabled".You can use DHCP on the WAN port. Not sure why you are bothering with VLAN settings though.

Comment: Do I have to use the WAN-Port? If so, I could only use it for the office-network (192..) since I need DHCP for the AP-Clients (2 Ports required for the APs)

Comment: Yes, you should use the WAN port. It will simplify setting things up, and eliminate the need for VLAN. You configure the WAN port to 192.168.178.101 and the LAN port to 10.0.0.1 with DHCP enabled. Install the AP's and set them to forward DHCP requests to the router. Done.

Comment: That worked. tack!